# Как взять строку при наведении на нее от пробела до пробела Python Tkinter?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

У меня есть метод, который работает при движении мыши:

```
def on_mouse_move(event):
    main_text.tag_remove("highlight", "1.0", tk.END)
    word = main_text.get(f"@{event.x},{event.y} wordstart",
                         f"@{event.x},{event.y} wordend")
    if word.lower() in words.wrong:
        main_text.tag_add("highlight",
                          f"@{event.x},{event.y} wordstart",
                          f"@{event.x},{event.y} wordend")
```

Сначала отчищаются все предыдущие теги, потом берется слово, на котором расположен курсор. Если оно находится в листе неправильных слов - оно подсвечивается.

Проблема в том, что `wordstart` и `wordend` в tkinter'е берут только буквенную строку. То есть, если есть строка `один-два-три`, то выделятся будут только те слова, на которые наведен курсор, без знаков тире, но мне нужно, чтобы вся строка `один-два-три` была выделена при наведении на любую часть строки `один-два-три`. Как это можно сделать?

**UPD1:**
Нашел [обсуждение с tcl](https://groups.google.com/g/comp.lang.tcl/c/6iqwChYethQ) и настройкой, что является строкой, а что нет. Пока разбираюсь.

**UPD2:**
Сделал как [в примере](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44625272/how-to-configure-default-double-mouse-click-behavior-in-tkinter-text-widget/44629998) @GrAnd, но все работает также (`-` не является буквой).
Вот весь (немного упрощенный) код:

```
import tkinter as tk


def on_mouse_move(event):
    text.tag_remove("highlight", "1.0", tk.END)
    text.tag_add("highlight", f"@{event.x},{event.y} wordstart",
                 f"@{event.x},{event.y} wordend")


def set_word_boundaries():
    # this first statement triggers tcl to autoload the library
    # that defines the variables we want to override.
    root.tk.call('tcl_wordBreakAfter', '', 0)
    # this defines what tcl considers to be a "word". For more
    # information see http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TclCmd/library.htm#M19
    root.tk.call('set', 'tcl_wordchars', '[a-zA-Z0-9-]')
    root.tk.call('set', 'tcl_nonwordchars', '[^a-zA-Z0-9-]')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = tk.Tk()
    set_word_boundaries()
    text = tk.Text(root)
    text.pack(fill="both", expand=True)
    text.insert("end", "foo 123-45-678 bar")
    text.tag_config("highlight", background="#94d2bd")
    text.bind("<Motion>", on_mouse_move)
    root.mainloop()
```

**UPD3:**
Оказывается все работает, но только при двойном нажатии на любое слово, а надо просто при наведении на него курсора мыши.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44625272/how-to-configure-default-double-mouse-click-behavior-in-tkinter-text-widget/44629998

Comment: Ну дык `<Motion>` указывает на то, что мышь перемещается с зажатой кнопкой: `<B1-Motion>`, `<B2-Motion>` и `<B3-Motion>` соответственно для левой, средней и правой кнопок. Может буду не прав, но проще использовать `Canvas` для выделения нужных блоков.

Comment: Только теги, потому что происходит выделение текста. Но вообще я уже все сделал - просто беру координаты курсора и в цикле беру слово по букве от пробела до пробела. Долго, но работает.